# How to change the attribute of an instance from an another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I am new to oop and I had a doubt.
Suppose we are in the main file and  had an instance of a class say `bot`
and, `bot.var = 5`
How do I edit `bot.var` in an *another* file such that the changes are reflected in the main file as well? Thanks for the help.

main.py :

```py
class Foo:
    ...


bar = Foo()
bar.var = 5
print(bar.var)
```

file.py :

```py
from main import Foo


class EditFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        # What do I do from here
        # such that the edits here are reflected on the main.py file
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: How are you going to run any code out of `file.py`?  Just having a file doesn’t do anything (which is good, if the alternative is all files running every time!).

Comment: Are you want to edit `Foo()` from `EditFoo()` .so when we call `Foo()` - `parent class` it will have attribute of EditFoo?

Comment: An another file (other than `main.py`) will call it, `main.py` calling will cause an circular import I believe. @DavisHerring

Comment: No I want to edit the `bar` instance and not tinker with the `Foo` class. I want to edit the attribute (namely `var` as in example) of bar instance, @Nguyen

Comment: You need to import `bar`, like you did with `Foo`.

Comment: @Lakh: Why is `main.py` not, well, the main program?  For an example meant to explain your question, you should certainly choose illustrative names!